# MIPS integer Sandy Bridge

Tags: assembly, x86

I wrote an arithmetic integer library in assembly. I would like to estimate the performance compared to the peak performance of my processor (Intel Sandy Bridge).

As integer arithmetic is performed by the 3 ALUs of the Sandy Bridge, is "3 * (number of cores) * frequency" enough to get an estimation ? 99% of my assembly is `addq, adcq, mulq` instructions).

Answer (score 1):

No.

There are many factors that influence the speed of any code. Things like dependencies between instructions that cause stalls, cache accesses and cache speed, cache misses and RAM speed, etc.

For Sandy Bridge specifically, there's also hyper-threading (those ALUs are shared by 2 logical CPUs) and turbo-boost and power management. Then there's paging (TLB lookup, and TLB misses).

On top of all that there's OS overhead; including things like how quickly the kernel can resolve page faults (for various "copy on write" and "allocate on write" purposes), how all work is scheduled across CPUs, how many task switches occur and how fast they are, how mutexes/futexes are handled, etc.

Comment: Thank all, it seems hard to have an answer. At least, I found : http://research.colfaxinternational.com/post/2012/04/30/FLOPS.aspx, I could make an approximation by basic proportionality rule (my code have 2/3 additions and 1/3 multiplication), experimental but better than nothing

Comment: Simply, I counted ASM instruction, I timed and I get 2.2 GIOPS on one core. As my lib, do long arithmetic as GMP I compared to GMP, I am 5 to 10 times faster (I have a static arithmetic lib not dynamic as gmp, means no dynamic allocation), I am happy, but I would like estimate what could be the theoretical potential of this proc. If I look the pdf I link, the theoretical peak is between 3.4 and 6.57 GIOPS for integer. So my results are quiet good, but I am not sure of this theoretical estimation

Answer (score 0):

If we were talking about a processor from the 1980's like a 8086 or 68000, then that would be valid, each instruction would run in a fixed time.

Modern Processors become very hard to benchmark manually as they pull so many tricks to make instructions run faster, large caches, pipelines, out of order instruction execution etc.. The best way is to time the code. You should also consider the effect of the code running in other cores when doing benchmarks. Your process can run at different speeds depending on overall loading on the processor, like in the latest i7 chips.

Comment: wikipedia says that the 8086 is a late 70's chip, tho ;)

Comment: while correct, it's main use was the 80's like in the first IBM PC in 1981. Like when I used it... :-)

Comment: nice. I was yet to see the light two years after that.

Comment: Additional question : do you have any idea of the origin of the carry bit or at least it first implementation ???

Comment: The carry bit was invented by sumerians 4000 BC. Used it on abacus.

Comment: A slightly newer version of carry, circa 1640 -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal's_calculator